# Que esquema debo seguir para enviar un archivo(txt) con ciertos datos a una nube, luego poder manipular los datos del archivo en una APP de android?

Tags: android, app, cloud

Investigando miro dos alternativas, enviar el archivo a la nube y descargarlo en la APP, para luego hacer uso de la informacion.

O enviar la informacion del archivo a una base de datos, y luego extraer la informacion de esta con la APP.

De ser asi, orientenme un poco el como hacerlo. O una mejor alternativa.

Comment: Mira [ask] <- ACA para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] <- ACA para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Esto es una pregunta que se considera basada en opiniones y no tiene una respuesta correcta acorde a los estandares que manejamos!! trata de arreglar la pregunta, para que tenga una sola respuesta valida.

Comment: encapsula la informacion dentro del txt en formato JSON, y cuando lo traigas de internet al archivo , lo descomprimis, lees todo con un StringBuilder , pasas todo a un string , lo pasas al JSONObject ... = new JSONObject(elstring); y ya podes trabajar parseando esos datos. O mas facil, subi directamente a tu endpoint por ej www.tupagina.com/miJson.php  y dentro de esa pagina tener el JSON plano, luego con httprequest solicitas los datos de esa pagina y los parseas, cuando acutalizas la pagina del json se actualiza la app. Ultima y mejor opcion : usar Firebase

Comment: Gracias por tu aporte, investigare al respecto y tratare de hacerlo de esa forma...